# Как остановить постоянную ajax подгрузку?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajax-load

При прокрутке до нужного места подгружаю часть сайта, но подгрузка постоянно происходит, не останавливается. Как сделать чтобы ajax запрос выполнялся только один раз?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
$('.scroll-here8').each(function() {var self = $(this),
height = self.offset().top + self.height();
if ($(document).scrollTop() + windowHeight >= height) {
$('#load_box_8').load('box8.html');
$('#box8, footer').addClass('soft-box8');
}});});});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогли на тостере:

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var isSended = false;
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
$('.scroll-here1').each(function() {var self = $(this),
height = self.offset().top + self.height();
if (!isSended && $(document).scrollTop() + windowHeight >= height) {
isSended = true;
$.ajax({
url: "box1.html",
cache: false,
beforeSend: function() {},
success: function(html){
$("#load_box_1").html(html);
$('#box1').fadeIn(1300);
}
});
return false;

}});
```

Comment: ужас *(6 символов нужно...)*

Comment: Вы о чем? Не понял

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  ...
  $(document).off('scroll');
});
```

Comment: Что-то не хочет работать

Comment: @МайклМиллер так и говорит: "Не хочу работать"?